# Mac Determining Minimized Applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

I'm trying to find a way in Objective-C to determine which applications are minimized to the dock. I've been using the following function to get information on all the windows in my user session:

```
CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID)
```

However, I haven't been able to identify any pattern in the return data that would let me know which windows are minimized.

Comment: Hi Travis were you able to find out a solution? Im having same issue.